# Generic Method for List of Generic Classes

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, methods

I have problem.
For example, considering these 4 classes.

```
public abstract ParentContainer<T> where T: Parentfoo
{
    public List<T> fooList; 
}

//Let there be many different ChildContainers with different types.
public class ChildContainer : ParentContainer<ChildFoo>
{
}

public abstract class ParentFoo
{
    public string name; 
}

public class ChildFoo : ParentFoo
{
}
```

How can I write a method which accepts a List of any arbitrary ChildContainers as a parameter,
which do operation on their fooLists?
Is it even possible?

Additional Explanation, there are many different childs of ParentContainer,
each with a List of a different child of foo.

```
public class ChildContainerB : ParentContainer<ChildFooB>{}
public class ChildContainerC : ParentCOntainer<ChildFooC>{}
...

public class ChildFooB : ParentFoo;
public class ChildFooC : ParentFoo;
```

Then I need a method something like this

```
//X means it can be any arbitrary ChildContainer
public void method(List<ChilContainerX> list) 
{
    foreach(ChildContainerX x in list)
    {
        print(x.fooList.Last().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: All `ChildContainer` instances will have a list of `ChildFoo`, so yes, this is possible but I suspect this is not what you want. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Could you at least make the example code you post compile? What is `foo`, did you mean `ParentFoo`?

Comment: Also, when you say *List of any arbitrary ChildContainers*, do you really mean to say *List of any objects that inherit from ParentContainer<T>*?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @GiulioCaccin Yes, sorry. I have corrected my example code!
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Is this a generic tree?

Comment: Probably you need a method like:
    public void method<T>(List<T> list) where T : ParentFoo

Answer (score 1):

So what you are asking isn't possible because you need a concrete type for the `List<>`. There are a couple of workarounds though.

1. Use `List<object>`. This is obviously not great because as it means you lose type checking completely and could end up with anything being added to the list. So for that reason, I wouldn't recommend this approach.
2. Make `ParentContainer<>` implement a marker interface. For example:

   ```
   public interface IParentContainer
   {
   }

   public abstract class ParentContainer<T> : IParentContainer
       where T: ParentFoo
   {
       //snip
   }
   ```

   And now you can have your list like this:

   ```
   var containers = new List<IParentContainer>
   {
       new ChildContainer(),
       new ChildContainer2()
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the question, you want something like this ...

```
public void DoStuffWith<T>(List<ParentContainer<T>> containers) where T : Parentfoo
{
     //TODO: implement
}
```

This would work on objects of type ...

```
List<ParentContainer<ParentFoo>>
List<ParentContainer<ChildFoo>>
```

where ChildFoo : ParentFoo

and solves the issue of "`List<ParentContainer<ParentFoo>>` does not implement `IEnumerable<ParentContainer<ChuldFoo>>`" which I suspect is the compiler you are seeing.

Taking this a step further something like ....

```
public void DoStuffWith<ContainerT,ElementT>(List<ContainerT<ElementT>> containers) 
  where ContainerT : ParentContainer 
  where ElementT : Parentfoo
{
     //TODO: implement
}
```

... likely over complicates the issue but i suspect is what you are trying to achieve.

At this point I would question the data structures you have and give them some common parent for example ...

```
public class ParentContainer<T> : IEnumerable<T> { ... }
public class ChildContainer<T> : ParentContainer<T>, IEnumerable<T> { ... }
```

Since both implement IEnumerable you can now do ...

```
public void DoStuffWith<T>(IEnumerable<T> containers) where T : ParentFoo
{
     //TODO: implement
}
```

This avoids the need to be concerned with the collection type at all.

Comment: I'm not asking for votes ... just trying to close the question. My bad, noted!

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the change in the question.

Comment: @War It's just something like I want. But your example is not fully correct.
Because `where T : ChildContainer` is for only one specific ChildContainer

Comment: Does the new version help ?

Comment: @war but I have a list of ChildContainers...
I can't pass `List<ChildContainerX>` to the method

Comment: I think i know what you are trying to say ... added more info :)

Comment: I guess it's just not possible with `List<ChildContainer>`...
Unfortunately I need this list, because I'm coding in Unity and lists will show up in the inspector only when it's not generic or abstract class

Comment: Unity doesn't handle Generics in the inspector at all only concrete types.
It also can't handle base type situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<ParentContainer<ChildFoo>> ca = new List<ParentContainer<ChildFoo>>();

        ProcessContainers processor = new ProcessContainers();

        ca.Add(new ChildContainerA { fooList = new List<ChildFoo>() });
        ca.Add(new ChildContainerA { fooList = new List<ChildFoo>() });
        ca.Add(new ChildContainerA { fooList = new List<ChildFoo>() });
        ca.Add(new ChildContainerB { fooList = new List<ChildFoo>() });

        processor.Process(ca);
    }
}


public abstract class ParentContainer<T> where T: ParentFoo
{
    public List<T> fooList;
}

//Let there be many different ChildContainers with different types.
public class ChildContainerA : ParentContainer<ChildFoo>
{
}
public class ChildContainerB : ParentContainer<ChildFoo>
{
}

public class ProcessContainers
{
    public void Process<T>(List<ParentContainer<T>> childContainers) where T : ParentFoo
    {
        foreach(var item in childContainers)
        {
            foreach(var foo in item.fooList)
            {
                foo.Porcess();
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class ParentFoo
{
    public string name;

    public abstract void Porcess();
}

public class ChildFoo : ParentFoo
{
    public override void Porcess()
    {
        //Do some processing
    }
}
```

Comment: ProcessContainers class can be used to process many containers with the foo list in it. Hope this would help

Comment: Hope this would help